# Grails test integration, controller injection

Tags: controller, integration, code-injection

I've to make an spock integration test for a controller which name is UsuarioController. In the test integratiion class I define a variable named usuarioController and when I execute the test, the variable contains null. Grails isnt injecting it automatically.

I've looked for this problem in foros and I 've read only one comment saying that grails cannot inject automatically a controller class in integration tests.

is it true ? is this true even the latest version of Grails?

(I'm now working with Grails version 2.4.5)

Thanyou very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about latest Grails Versions (I am still using Grails 2.2.2 at the moment)

You will have to instantiate the controller yourself in the setup() Method:

```
def controller

void setup() {
   controller = new FoobarController()
}
```

But be aware, that (in contrast to unit tests) all services defined in FoobarController, will be injected automatically to the controller instance!